# Postgres + Hibernate + Java UUID

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee, uuid

I want to use PostgreSQL's native UUID type with a Java UUID.  I am using Hibernate as my JPA provider and ORM.  If I try to save it directly, it is just saved as a bytea in Postgres.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try use the latest development version of the JDBC driver (Currently 8.4dev-700), or wait for the next release version. (Edited to add: 8.4-701 has been released)

The [release notes](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/changes.html#version_8.4dev-700) mention this change:

> Map the database uuid type to java.util.UUID. This only works for relatively new server (8.3) and JDK (1.5) versions.

Comment: This seems to be failing presently with the driver version 9.2-1002 and hibernate-core 3.3.1.GZ. There is a outstanding unanswered question at https://community.jboss.org/thread/229747?_sscc=t. I also run into a problem with this using GORM.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a repost of my answer on [Postgresql UUID supported by Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495233/postgresql-uuid-supported-by-hibernate/7479035#7479035) ... I know this question is old, but if someone stumbles across it, this will help them out.

This can be solved by adding the following annotation to the UUID:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
...
@Type(type="pg-uuid")
private java.util.UUID itemUuid;
```

As to why Hibernate doesn't just make this the default setting, I couldn't tell you...

**UPDATE**: There still seem to be issues using the `createNativeQuery` method to open objects that have UUID fields. Fortunately, the `createQuery` method so far has worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

you could try with:

```
 @Column(name="foo", columnDefinition="uuid")
```

where columnDefinition is a fragment of native SQL

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Column(name = "UUID", nullable=false, insertable = false, columnDefinition="uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()")
private String uuid;
```

Answer (score 0):

In non-JPA usage I'd create a UserType to format the UUID as a string that PostgreSQL accepts, then just give the name of the UserType implementation as the column type.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can get UUID type to be auto-converted to a String (uuid.toString() should give the canonical 36-char representation)? DBs usually convert things reliably between Strings and native types.