# Liquibase generates bigint IDs instead of varchar

Tags: database, postgresql, database-schema, liquibase, dropwizard

I'm just trying out Liquibase with Dropwizard and Hibernate on PostgreSQL, all latest versions, but I've hit a snag. I was going to use Hibernate's UUID generator for my class IDs, which produces a String PK. I specified I wanted a `varchar(32)` field called `id` in my tables, but Liquidbase generated `bigint` fields instead. Interestingly however, the two tables got different columns: `portfolio.id` has the sequence `portfolio_id_seq`, whereas Stock has no sequence.

Did I do something wrong, or is this just some weird property of Liquibase's ID columns? Should I be using `bigint`s? Code below:

**migrations.xml:**

```
<changeSet id="1" author="orlade">
    <createTable tableName="stock">
        <column name="id" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="symbol" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="description" type="varchar(255)" />
    </createTable>

    <createTable tableName="portfolio">
        <column name="id" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="description" type="varchar(255)" />
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

**Portfolio.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "portfolio")
public class Portfolio {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
  private String id;
}
```

**Stock.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
  private String id;
}
```

Comment: Probably won't help, but shouldn't [UUID](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-uuid.html) be the correct type to use?

Comment: Well, if you're storing uuid you don't use a sequence generator, you set `DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()` after adding the `ossp-uuid` contrib module, or you let your app generate them. Sounds like your ORM isn't getting the message that you want UUIDs.

Comment: Indeed, if I'm using UUIDs I suppose I should let Hibernate know too. After doing that it still created bigint columns, though.

Answer (score 3):

So although I can't find a list of valid Liquidbase types, it turns out that `UUID` is one, so I used that, and changed the Java types to `java.util.UUID` as well. This seemed to be enough to get Liquidbase to create columns of type `uuid`, but then I started getting errors in Java about being unable to write String to UUID or whatever.

The (or at least a) solution turned out to be to use the @Type annotation to specify the type you want Hibernate to convert the value to before writing to the database. Just saying it's a `java.util.UUID` doesn't seem to be sufficient. The below setup worked:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Type(type = "pg-uuid")
private UUID id;
```

The `uuid2` strategy can [generate UUID, String or byte[16] values](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id), and by default it seems to try to write to Postgres using the `bytea` type. Specifying the type fixed this up (as per [Postgresql UUID supported by Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7479035/363039)), and I also don't know why it's not the default.