# Hibernate named query with UUID as parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, uuid

I am attempting to use a named query against a Postgres database to select all rows with a given UUID (being used as a foreign key). Here is the named query that is being called.

```
  @NamedNativeQuery(name = "getAllXByFK",
  query = "SELECT * FROM table n WHERE FK = :param",
    resultClass = Foobar.class)})
```

I set the parameter using the java.util.UUID type.

```
query.setParameter(param.getKey(), param.getValue());
```

When I go to get the ResultSet with `query.list()` the following error is reported:

ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = bytea

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495233/postgresql-uuid-supported-by-hibernate
You could try to implement a usertype similar to the patch in HHH-3579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really beautiful, but this worked for me:

SQL:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("... where cast(c.id as varchar) = :id ");
```

Parameter set like this:

```
query.setString("id", myUUID.toString());
```

I only wonder if PostgreSQL does still use the index on `id` if a cast is performed on the column... ?

**Edit:**

With Hibernate 5.0.9 I strangely do not need the ugly cast, I can set the parameter as expected with:

```
query.setParameter("id", myUUID);
```

**Edit 2019-05-11:**

For SQL queries I tend to use jdbcTemplate in my Hibernate projects now. Just autowire it and use it:

```
@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate  jdbcTemplate;

// ...

MapSqlParameterSource p = new MapSqlParameterSource("name", "value");
p.addValue("anotherParam", true);
List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select ... where id = :name", p);
```

Comment: It does not use index. Without cast when explain gives `Index Scan...` after cast explain gives `Seq Scan...`

Answer (score 1):

Usually this error is reported when you supply a `null` value for the bind parameter.