# Failed to store java.time.ZonedDateTime using hibernate PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have an entity which extends an auditing entity class named AbstractAuditingEntity in which one of the field is

```
@CreatedDate
@Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private ZonedDateTime createdDate
```

Above field has mapping to database field named `"created_date"` with type `"timestamp without time zone"`.

But at the time of saving this entity PostgresSQL throws error as follows :

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "created_date" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I looked for the same error & found solution here : [Postgresql UUID supported by Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495233/postgresql-uuid-supported-by-hibernate)

But the solution is for `java.util.UUID`, in solution it is suggested to add annotation  `@Type(type="pg-uuid")` on a field with UUID type.

Is there any such a ready-to-use type value like `pg-uuid` for `ZonedDateTime` ? Any reference link for the different values constants of hibernate `@Type` annotation ?

Or am supposed to write a custom deserializer class ? How to write such deserializer class any reference link ?

```
PostgresSQL Version  : 9.6,
<liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.6</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
```

Comment: Can you enable debug logs on `org.hibernate.type` in your logger? You should find something like this if the types are registered http://pastebin.com/t2xh5UvM and should work.

Comment: Before Hibernate 5.2 the handling of Java 8 time classes came in an optional module.

Answer (score 8):

For Hibernate 5.2 it should just work out of the box.

For 5.0 you can add a dependency to support it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

For 4.3 you can use a JPA 2.1 converter:

```
@Converter
public class TimestampConverter implements AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, Timestamp> {
    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(ZonedDateTime zonedTime) {
        if (zonedTime == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Timestamp(zonedTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp localTime) {
        if (localTime == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(localTime.getTime()), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
}
```

Then annotate your attribute with `@Convert`:

```
@Convert(converter = TimestampConverter.class)
private ZonedDateTime createdDate;
```

I note that your database column is `TIMESTAMP`. It should really be `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, especially if your client time zone has daylight savings changes.

Comment: Notice that you lose timezone information in your solution for 4.3.

Comment: Postgres doesn't store offset information in `TIMESTAMP` or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.