# Foreign key column of type UUID throws "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea"

Tags: java, postgresql-9.6, hibernate-4.x

I have one table in which primary column if of type uuid. The same column is referenced as foreign key in another table. When i try to insert data to foreign table from hibernate i get "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column  is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression." Exception. If any one have encountered this issue please reply to the post.

Primary table ID generation

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
@Type(type = "pg-uuid")
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
public UUID getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Foreign Table reference

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id",  columnDefinition="uuid")
public Company getCompanyid() {
    return companyid;
}
```

Error is thrown when saving data to foreign table not the primary table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql UUID supported by Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495233/postgresql-uuid-supported-by-hibernate)

Comment: I tried the approach given in the link. It did not work. I get the exception still.