# How to map List<UUID> to array with Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm setting up a table in Postgres, and want to map List to jdbc array type using custom @Converter class. But I

> get org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 984991021

```
//StoredJob class for creating table:
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs")
public class StoredJob {
 ....
//The error is here
@Column
@Convert(converter = JobFileListConverter.class)
private List<UUID> jobFiles;

//Converter class:
@Converter
public class JobFileListConverter implements 
                        AttributeConverter<List<UUID>, UUID[]> {
@Override
public UUID[] convertToDatabaseColumn(List<UUID> uuidList) {
    return uuidList.toArray(UUID[]::new);
}

@Override
public List<UUID> convertToEntityAttribute(UUID[] uuidArray) {
    return Arrays.asList(uuidArray);
}
```

Comment: What is your database schema ? I've used many times mapping to lists and I never encountered issues or needed a converter. If you're removing your converter it does not work ?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststring-in-jpa and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495233/postgresql-uuid-supported-by-hibernate perhaps

Comment: A Le Dref, if i remove converter i get another exception: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: jobs, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(job_files)

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
private List<UUID> jobFiles;
```

with this one:

```
private UUID[] jobFiles;
```

But, I strongly suggest you to remove '@Convert' annotation and add a getter method as below:

```
public UUID[] getJobFiles() {
    return jobFiles.stream().toArray(UUID[]::new);
}
```

Comment: But what if i want to operate with jobFiles as a list?

Comment: You can handle it using different getter/setter