# UUID[] in hibernate not mapping

Tags: database, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, uuid

My question is similar to [Postgresql UUID supported by Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495233/postgresql-uuid-supported-by-hibernate) but I have to use array of UUID. I receive the error

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "system_ids" is of type uuid[] but expression is of type bytea
```

Column definition is

```
@Column(name = "system_ids", columnDefinition = "uuid[]")
private UUID[] system_ids;
```

I am using Postgresql so I have mapped other UUID pk's as

```
@Type(type = "pg-uuid")
```

I do not know how to map UUID[]

Comment: Last I checked the PGJDBC driver does not support uuid arrays. That was about a year ago, but I doubt it's changed.

Comment: I am using hibernate 4.3.11 and it works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution. I am using hibernate 4.3.11.Final due to some issues and couldn't use the typedef class UUIDArrayType.class so I imported the dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-5</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now my code looks like this

```
...

@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "uuid-array", typeClass = UUIDArrayType.class) })
...

    @Type(type = "uuid-array")
    @Column(name = "system_ids", columnDefinition = "uuid[]")
    private UUID[] system_ids;

...
```