# JTS - Hibernate + Postgres + UUID conflict

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-spatial

I'm using Hibernate 5.0 + Postgres 9.4

My entities use `UUID`s as indentifier.

The project also uses `hibernate-spatial`.

The `id` property is annotated simply as

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private UUID id;
```

After persisting any entity (not only the ones with geometrical data), I get the following error:

```
column "id" is of type geometry but expression is of type uuid
```

Looks like there is some conflict in types mapping to me; though I'm not an expert of Hibernate types mapping.

Is there anyone who can help me overcome this issue?

Comment: What is the type of column `ID` in the database?

Comment: @SubOptimal It is created as `geometry`, because both `UUID` and `Geometry` are mapped to `java.sql.Types.OTHER`

Comment: You mean you have `CREATE TABLE some_table (id geometry, ...)` and now want to map the `UUID` to it?

Comment: @SubOptimal Nope. Schema (in dev mode) was created by Hibernate. As long as I didn't add the spatial integration (hibernate-spatial:5.0.7) the UUID fields were created correctly as `pg-uuid`. After adding spatial stuff, the mapping changed due to the fact that both `java.util.UUID` and `com.vividsolutions.Geometry` are mapped to `java.sql.Types.OTHER`. Now, the problem is how to workaround this mapping conflict.

Comment: Maybe this could be the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495233/postgresql-uuid-supported-by-hibernate#7479035.

Comment: @SubOptimal yes, this is actually a solution (hence the +1). Though it has a couple of flaws: 1. Entities are Hibernate aware; 2. Entities are database specific. The optimal outcome would be to have all entities reusable with different ORMs and different DBMS. I've been working on that quite some hours now, and the only solution I found is to treat UUIDs as strings (which is not very performant)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41234990/1562477) and the original [discussion thread](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9562?focusedCommentId=66756&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-66756)

Specifying `columnDefinition = "uuid"` solved exactly the same issue for me.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column( columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false )
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```