# How to create attribute converter for @id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In jpa (>= 2.1) how can you create an AttributeConverter for an attribute annotated with @Id?

Unfortunately, it seems like Hibernate does not allow it in the following code:
org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder#applyAttributeConverter

```
if ( property.isAnnotationPresent( Id.class ) ) {
            LOG.debugf( "Skipping AttributeConverter checks for Id attribute [%s]", property.getName() );
            return;
}
```

Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you using as the PK?

Comment: That's a shame, since other JPA providers do allow it, and can't see a good reason why not to allow it ...

Comment: You should file a ticket to have it changed https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH. They probably had some internal design considerations for it when they made the restriction, but maybe they're not valid any more and it could be just legacy code.

Comment: Ok, I just found the answer for it.
Seems like JPA specs does not allow it.
See: 
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8820
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9172
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8809
Seems really stupid IMHO, but... Will look for an alternative. @Kayaman I am using my own Date type as primary key. I'd really appreciate if any one has a suggestion, thanks!

Comment: A date as a primary key, ouch. :) Have you considered a surrogate key?

Comment: @Kayaman Yeah, I agree with you. Unfortunately I have no say at the database design, nor is it changeable anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Just found a nice workaround as I had the same problem as Hibernate was serializing the object even with @Convert all the time, except... for those where I used it inside an @Embeddable

```
  @Embeddable
  public static class Key {
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @Convert(converter = MyObjectConverter.class)
    private MyObject id;
//getter/setter
  }

  @EmbeddedId
  private Key key;
```

Comment: The downside is that instead of doing `myEntity.id` you now need to do `myEntity.key.id`, both in JPQL queries and in actual Java property access.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that you can use UUID as an id and then converter is allowed
[Persisting UUID in PostgreSQL using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284359/persisting-uuid-in-postgresql-using-jpa/17323965#17323965)
It's strange you can't use any custom Converter