# How to get String UUID in JPA and store as VARCHAR in Postgresql database?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

How to achieve the following (if it's possible):

**Create table in DB**

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
    id UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**Create Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Sample {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "char(36)")
  @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
  private String id;
```

Basically, I want to generate UUID but store it as String in PostgreSQL database and use it as String in Java code too.

Comment: Relevant: [Persisting UUID in PostgreSQL using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284359/persisting-uuid-in-postgresql-using-jpa)

Comment: You would be far better off generating and storing as UUID, then converting to text (string) on  when selected. `select id::text, ... `.